# PHP and MYSQL authentication

Tags: php, mysql

my login function does not work, always says username or password does not work. i need echo ok if username and password are correct so i can continue with my project. my db password is set to md5. here are y codes:

user.php file

```
<?php

<?php
function sanitize($username)//sanitizes user inputs
{ $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','lr'); 
return mysqli_real_escape_string
($connect,$username); } 
?>

//checks if user exist
function user_exists($username)
{ $username = sanitize($username);
    $conn = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lr') OR die("cant connect");

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    return(mysqli_num_rows($query) ==1) ? true : false;
}


//checks if user active, if set in database to 1, its active, if set to 0, not active
function user_active($username)
{ $username = sanitize($username);
    $conn = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lr') OR die("cant connect");

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND active =1");
    return(mysqli_num_rows($query) ==1) ? true : false;
}

//Gets user id from username
function user_id_from_username ($username) {
        $username = sanitize ($username);
        return mysql_result(mysqli_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}
function login($username, $password){
        $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

        $username = sanitize($username);
        $password = MD5($password);

        return (mysql_result(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'"), 0)==1) ? $user_id : false;
}



?>

login.php file


<?php
function sanitize($username)
{ $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','lr'); 
return mysqli_real_escape_string
($connect,$username); } 
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you have more than one username : change this : `return(mysqli_num_rows($query) ==1) ? true : false;`   TO this :  `return(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) ? true : false;`

Comment: Please do not suppress error messages. Fix them as they pop up. If you're expecting an error to be thrown once in a while, handle it. Don't suppress.

Comment: You can check by running check_user function's query in phpmyadmin that how many records are in result set.